# gridstack.js - keep aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-resizable, gridstack

I'm using [gridstack.js](https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js) and need to maintain aspect ratio on-resize.
I've tried many ways I found on google but nothing is working.
Following is a link to JSFiddle I made to demonstrate the issue:
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dqyvh6vr/3/)

```
var options = {
    aspectRatio: 16/9
  };

  $('.grid-stack').gridstack(options);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this...

```
var options = {
resizable:{
    aspectRatio: 16/9
  }
};

$('.grid-stack').gridstack(options);
```